# IB Constraints dont show the same on device

Tags: xcode, constraints, interface-builder

I have a problem with Xcode IB constraints. To be frank, I never used it and now I inherited a project where I need to bring a fix.
IB shows things correctly, but at run time I get somethin different. I tried to play with some of the parameters in IB, but nothing helps.

So, my question is: How can I get on the device what I see in IB.
Here's IB:

[image]

On the device, the 'Fin de Course' is going into next field and Promo Code gets stuck.
What can I do?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you already set the constraint correctly but your view is different when the app is running compared to Interface Builder or Storyboard. My suggestion is try to check the "orange" constraint. This is where the view gets "wrong" position on runtime.

The solution is to click the view which has "orange" constraint, then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>  in the keyboard. You will see the position will be updated.

But if you want to change the position of the view, you cannot just drag and drop if the constraints are still exist. The old constraint will still active. You have to update the constraint manually. You also can delete all constraints of the view first, then drag and drop the view into your desired location, and then set the new constraint.